# JavaScript / Ajax firefox 3.0.x

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a problem with JS or Ajax (I don't know).

I have a button on a web page (html) that is associated with a JS onClick event. This JS works fine for every browser execpt firefox 3.0.x

I don't know where the problem is.

I attach the code so someone can tell me something about that.

Thank you in advance.

S.

```
var currLanguage = "en";
var request;
var queryString;

function confermaSalvataggio(reservationsList)
{
    var messaggioHeader = new Array();
    var messaggioFooter = new Array();
    messaggioHeader['it'] = "ATTENZIONE! I dati caricati nel pannello non sono più aggiornati a causa di prenotazioni o cancellazioni avvenute dall'apertura del pannello stesso.\n\n";
    messaggioFooter['it'] = "\nContinuare con le VOSTRE modifiche ? Premendo OK i vostri dati verranno salvati e dovrete verificarne la correttezza in seguito manualmente. Premendo ANNULLA (consigliato) verrete riportati al pannello dove potrete appuntarvi i dati appena inseriti, ricaricare il pannello (manualmente) ed inserirli nuovamente mantenendo il loro stato congruente con le prenotazioni/cancellazioni appena giunte";
    messaggioHeader['en'] = "CAUTION! Data loaded on the panel isn't up to date due to reservations or cancellations occurred since panel open. \n\n"
    messaggioFooter['en'] = "\nDo you want to continue with changes ? By clicking OK YOUR data will saved and, then, you'll have to verify the correctness in a manual way. By clicking  CANCEL (recommended) you'll come back on the panel where you can clip out data just inserted, reload the panel (manually) and insert again data keeping data state congruent with reservations/cancellations just come";
    messaggioHeader['fr'] = messaggioHeader['en'];
    messaggioFooter['fr'] = messaggioFooter['en'];
    messaggioHeader['es'] = messaggioHeader['en'];
    messaggioFooter['es'] = messaggioFooter['en'];
    messaggioHeader['de'] = messaggioHeader['en'];
    messaggioFooter['de'] = messaggioFooter['en'];

    if ( reservationsList != "\n" )
    {
        var messaggio = messaggioHeader[currLanguage]+reservationsList+messaggioFooter[currLanguage];
        var flag = confirm(messaggio);
        if (flag)
        {
            document.tariffe.submit();
        }
    }
    else
    {
       document.tariffe.submit();
    }
}

function handleSaveResponse()
{
  if (request.readyState == 4)
  {
    if (request.status == 200)
    {
      var response = this.responseText;
      confermaSalvataggio(response);
    }
    else
    {
      //alert("Risposta del web service: " + request.status);
    }
  }
}

function initializeRequestObject()
{
  var msxmlhttp = new Array('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.5.0', 'Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0', 'Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0', 'Msxml2.XMLHTTP', 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

  if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined")
  {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < msxmlhttp.length; i++)
    {
      try
      {
        request = new ActiveXObject(msxmlhttp[i]);
      }
      catch (e)
      {
        request = null;
     }
    }
  }
}

function initReq(reqType, url, bool)
{
  if (request)
  {
    try
    {
      request.open(reqType, url, bool);
    }
    catch (e)
    {
      errorsString = 'Errore nella funzione initReq(), metodo request.open: ' + e;
      alert(errorsString);
    }

    try
    {
      request.onreadystatechange = handleSaveResponse;
      request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
      errorsString = "Errore nella funzione initReq(), metodo request.onreadystatechange: " + e;
      alert(errorsString);
    }

    try
    {
      request.send(queryString);
    }
    catch (e)
    {
      errorsString = "Errore nella funzione initReq(), metodo request.send: " + e;
      alert(errorsString);
    }
  }
}


function httpRequest(reqType, url, asynch)
{
  initializeRequestObject();
  if (request)
  {
    initReq(reqType, url, asynch);
  }
  else
  {
    notifyError("Errore in httpRequest(): oggetto XmlHttpRequest non inizializzato correttamente");
  }
}


function controlReservations(hotel_id,data_server,data_da,data_a,lingua)
{
  try
  {
    queryString = "hid=" + hotel_id + "&ds=" + data_server + "&dd=" + data_da + "&da=" + data_a + "&lingua=" + lingua;
    httpRequest("POST", "hotelLastReservations", false);

    // MI SERVIRANNO !?!? //
    //pagina = base_url + "/" + entity
    //alert(pagina);
    //window.location = pagina;
    // MI SERVIRANNO !?!? //
  }
  catch (e)
  {
    notifyError("Errore in toggleAttiva(): " + e);
  }
}
```

I've just found the solution. Firefox < 4 doesn't support ajax synchronous handler. If i switch to async. handler it works in the right way.

Comment: I'd be very tempted to stick up a "Your browser is no longer supported by your vendor, has known security problems, and known bugs with this site. We recommend you upgrade to a more recent version immediately" message.

Comment: Don't use an array if you want named keys, use an object. Arrays for for when you have a series of numeric keys.

Comment: I have no apparently error but the button don't do what it have to do...

Comment: @Quentin: is a temporary solution

Comment: Does this work in FireFox 4 or 5?

Comment: Less than 2% of Firefox users use Firefox versions < 3.5.

Comment: @csharpsi: yes @Azmisov: yes I know but we have some costumer that use it

Comment: in your **initializeRequestObject()** function, your handling code for msxml is incorrect. it will try to create 5 instances of of ActiveXObject, and will only save the last one. change the loop's condition or use a **break**.

Comment: Don't write "solved" in questions please. Write an answer and accept it, if you solved it yourself. Stack Overflow is not a message board.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
var messaggioHeader = new Array();
var messaggioFooter = new Array();
```

with this:

```
var messaggioHeader = {};
var messaggioFooter = {};
```

Comment: It isn't compatible in our opinion ? I'll try , btw

Comment: Can you add the html snippet ? And leave out the cross-browser ajax method, it's noisy and doesn't bring anything that helps solving the problem